# How to check to see if one view is on top of another view?

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, frame, cgpoint

Currently there is a scrollview (whole screen) that sits behind a uiview (bottom portion of the screen). I"m trying to check whether or not a label on the scroll is covered by the uiview (this happens with iphone se).  Is there a way to check if the uiview is covering the label on the scrollview?  I tried using the center cgpoint of a label on the scrollview to see if its smaller than a point on the uiview but it won't allow me to compare two cgpoints for size:

```
if atmLabel.center < CGPoint(x: 156, y: 570) {
    buttonView.dropShadow(shadowOpacity: 0.5)
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For point checking, you should use

contains function of CGRect... in short this should work

```
 let view = UIView()
 let label = UILabel()

 if label.frame.contains(view.frame) {
    //Do your stuff...
 }
```

You can use the view hiearchy with Xcode with this button [image]

Or you can simply print out on the current viewController subviews

```
print(self.view.subviews)
```

this prints out array of UIView subclasses sorted by ascending order of layer on the view... I recommend the first way of debugging :)

Comment: That's great for debugging, but I need it to execute something if the label is covered.  Is there a way to find out in code?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to see if two views overlap in code, I think this should work:

```
if view1.frame.intersects(view2.frame) {
    // handle overlap
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your view hierarchy:

```
parentView
- scrollView
- - label
- topView
```

> The frame rectangle, which describes the view’s location and size in its superview’s coordinate system.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame

You can't simply compare frames of `label` and `topView`, because `frame` is position in superview's coordinates aka `topView.frame` is in `parentView` coordinates and `label.frame` is in `scrollView` coordinates.

So you need to transform either `label` to `parentView` or `topView` to `scrollView` coordinates. Let's go with first variant:

```
let frameInParent = parentView.convert(label.frame, from: label.superview)
```

After that you can check if this frame intersects with `topView`'s:

```
let isOverlaps = frameInParent.intersects(topView.frame)
```

But this only true if you don't use any transforms on views, because again frame documentation:

> Warning
>
> If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.